# Getting TypeError when trying to concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, typeerror

I have the following code:
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

```
def hltvmatch_spider(max_offset):
    offset = 0
    while offset < max_offset:
        url = 'http://www.hltv.org/?pageid=188&offset=' + str(offset)
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, 'html.parser')
        for link in soup.findAll('a'):
            href = "http://www.hltv.org" + link.get('href')
            print(href)
        offset += 50

hltvmatch_spider(1)
```

which is returning and error:

```
href = "http://www.hltv.org" + link.get('href')
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects
```

Any ideas what I need to change for fix? THANKS FOR THE HELP!!

Comment: What links are you trying to get exactly, pulling every anchor does not seem like a great idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set *href=True* so you only get anchors with href attributes, calling `.get("href")` will return None when the anchor has no href attribute:

```
for link in soup.findAll('a', href=True):
```

As I commented getting all anchors is not probably what you want as joining to the base url is not going to work, this will get all the anchor tags from the main content:

```
cont = soup.select_one("div.covMainBoxContent")

print([a["href"] for a in cont.select("a[href]")])
```

Which would give you:

```
['/?pageid=188&matchid=31342', '/?pageid=179&teamid=4411', '/?pageid=179&teamid=5995', '/?pageid=188&eventid=2135', '/?pageid=188&matchid=31343', '/?pageid=179&teamid=4548', '/?pageid=179&teamid=6865', '/?pageid=188&eventid=2254', '/?pageid=188&matchid=31339', '/?pageid=179&teamid=4548', '/?pageid=179&teamid=6865', '/?pageid=188&eventid=2254', '/?pageid=188&matchid=31338', '/?pageid=179&teamid=5995', '/?pageid=179&teamid=6736', '/?pageid=188&eventid=2135', '/?pageid=188&matchid=31341', '/?pageid=179&teamid=6620', '/?pageid=179&teamid=6807', '/?pageid=188&eventid=2238', '/?pageid=188&matchid=31340', '/?pageid=179&teamid=6807', '/?pageid=179&teamid=6620', '/?pageid=188&eventid=2238', '/?pageid=188&matchid=31329', '/?pageid=179&teamid=5995', '/?pageid=179&teamid=6736', '/?pageid=188&eventid=2135', '/?pageid=188&matchid=31336', '/?pageid=179&teamid=6998', '/?pageid=179&teamid=4602', '/?pageid=188&eventid=2262', '/?pageid=188&matchid=31334', '/?pageid=179&teamid=4602', '/?pageid=179&teamid=6998', '/?pageid=188&eventid=2262', '/?pageid=188&matchid=31331', '/?pageid=179&teamid=4674', '/?pageid=179&teamid=6133', '/?pageid=188&eventid=2254', '/?pageid=188&matchid=31330', '/?pageid=179&teamid=6133', '/?pageid=179&teamid=4674', '/?pageid=188&eventid=2254', '/?pageid=188&matchid=31333', '/?pageid=179&teamid=4501', '/?pageid=179&teamid=6686', '/?pageid=188&eventid=2232', '/?pageid=188&matchid=31332', '/?pageid=179&teamid=4501', '/?pageid=179&teamid=6686', '/?pageid=188&eventid=2232', '/?pageid=188&matchid=31319', '/?pageid=179&teamid=4411', '/?pageid=179&teamid=6615', '/?pageid=188&eventid=2135', '/?pageid=188&matchid=31321', '/?pageid=179&teamid=6133', '/?pageid=179&teamid=5929', '/?pageid=188&eventid=2262', '/?pageid=188&matchid=31320', '/?pageid=179&teamid=5929', '/?pageid=179&teamid=6133', '/?pageid=188&eventid=2262', '/?pageid=188&matchid=31318', '/?pageid=179&teamid=6615', '/?pageid=179&teamid=4411', '/?pageid=188&eventid=2135', '/?pageid=188&matchid=31328', '/?pageid=179&teamid=6222', '/?pageid=179&teamid=6408', '/?pageid=188&eventid=2232', '/?pageid=188&matchid=31327', '/?pageid=179&teamid=6408', '/?pageid=179&teamid=6222', '/?pageid=188&eventid=2232', '/?pageid=188&matchid=31326', '/?pageid=179&teamid=6621', '/?pageid=179&teamid=6968', '/?pageid=188&eventid=2252', '/?pageid=188&matchid=31325', '/?pageid=179&teamid=6621', '/?pageid=179&teamid=6968', '/?pageid=188&eventid=2252', '/?pageid=188&matchid=31324', '/?pageid=179&teamid=6619', '/?pageid=179&teamid=6785', '/?pageid=188&eventid=2252', '/?pageid=188&matchid=31322', '/?pageid=179&teamid=6619', '/?pageid=179&teamid=6785', '/?pageid=188&eventid=2252', '/?pageid=188&matchid=31317', '/?pageid=179&teamid=4548', '/?pageid=179&teamid=6407', '/?pageid=188&eventid=2254', '/?pageid=188&matchid=31316', '/?pageid=179&teamid=4548', '/?pageid=179&teamid=6407', '/?pageid=188&eventid=2254', '/?pageid=188&matchid=31315', '/?pageid=179&teamid=6995', '/?pageid=179&teamid=7009', '/?pageid=188&eventid=2253', '/?pageid=188&matchid=31306', '/?pageid=179&teamid=6995', '/?pageid=179&teamid=7009', '/?pageid=188&eventid=2253', '/?pageid=188&matchid=31314', '/?pageid=179&teamid=4501', '/?pageid=179&teamid=6686', '/?pageid=188&eventid=2262', '/?pageid=188&matchid=31310', '/?pageid=179&teamid=6686', '/?pageid=179&teamid=4501', '/?pageid=188&eventid=2262', '/?pageid=188&matchid=31304', '/?pageid=179&teamid=6889', '/?pageid=179&teamid=6994', '/?pageid=188&eventid=2253', '/?pageid=188&matchid=31302', '/?pageid=179&teamid=6994', '/?pageid=179&teamid=6889', '/?pageid=188&eventid=2253', '/?pageid=188&matchid=31313', '/?pageid=179&teamid=6865', '/?pageid=179&teamid=4688', '/?pageid=188&eventid=2255', '/?pageid=188&matchid=31312', '/?pageid=179&teamid=4688', '/?pageid=179&teamid=6865', '/?pageid=188&eventid=2255', '/?pageid=188&matchid=31311', '/?pageid=179&teamid=4688', '/?pageid=179&teamid=6865', '/?pageid=188&eventid=2255', '/?pageid=188&matchid=31309', '/?pageid=179&teamid=4602', '/?pageid=179&teamid=6408', '/?pageid=188&eventid=2232', '/?pageid=188&matchid=31308', '/?pageid=179&teamid=4602', '/?pageid=179&teamid=6408', '/?pageid=188&eventid=2232', '/?pageid=188&matchid=31307', '/?pageid=179&teamid=4602', '/?pageid=179&teamid=6408', '/?pageid=188&eventid=2232', '/?pageid=188&matchid=31305', '/?pageid=179&teamid=6133', '/?pageid=179&teamid=4548', '/?pageid=188&eventid=2254', '/?pageid=188&matchid=31303', '/?pageid=179&teamid=4548', '/?pageid=179&teamid=6133', '/?pageid=188&eventid=2254', '/?pageid=188&matchid=31294', '/?pageid=179&teamid=4869', '/?pageid=179&teamid=6137', '/?pageid=188&eventid=2176', '/?pageid=188&matchid=31293', '/?pageid=179&teamid=6137', '/?pageid=179&teamid=4869', '/?pageid=188&eventid=2176', '/?pageid=188&matchid=31292', '/?pageid=179&teamid=4869', '/?pageid=179&teamid=6137', '/?pageid=188&eventid=2176', '/?pageid=188&matchid=31291', '/?pageid=179&teamid=4548', '/?pageid=179&teamid=6407', '/?pageid=188&eventid=2232', '/?pageid=188&matchid=31290', '/?pageid=179&teamid=4548', '/?pageid=179&teamid=6407', '/?pageid=188&eventid=2232', '/?pageid=188&matchid=31289', '/?pageid=179&teamid=4548', '/?pageid=179&teamid=6407', '/?pageid=188&eventid=2232', '/?pageid=188&matchid=31301', '/?pageid=179&teamid=5996', '/?pageid=179&teamid=6981', '/?pageid=188&eventid=2273', '/?pageid=188&matchid=31300', '/?pageid=179&teamid=5996', '/?pageid=179&teamid=6981', '/?pageid=188&eventid=2273', '/?pageid=188&matchid=31299', '/?pageid=179&teamid=5996', '/?pageid=179&teamid=6869', '/?pageid=188&eventid=2273', '/?pageid=188&matchid=31298', '/?pageid=179&teamid=5996', '/?pageid=179&teamid=6869', '/?pageid=188&eventid=2273', '/?pageid=188&matchid=31297', '/?pageid=179&teamid=6981', '/?pageid=179&teamid=6792', '/?pageid=188&eventid=2273']
```

If you are not more specific you will get links like:

```
 http://static.hltv.org//images/category/5.gif
```

when + with `http://www.hltv.org` is not going to work well.

To get the links under the first i.e  *date* column we can add `a[href*=matchid=]` to our select, the html layout is not very nice to parse as there is not what I would call a reliable way to parse the data but since `matchid=` is unique to the hrefs in that column that will work.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("http://www.hltv.org/?pageid=188&offset=1").content)
cont = soup.select("div.covMainBoxContent a[href*=matchid=]")

print([a["href"] for a in cont])
```

To get the full html you need to join the base url to the href:

```
from urlparse import urljoin

base = "http://www.hltv.org/"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("http://www.hltv.org/?pageid=188&offset=1").content)
cont = soup.select("div.covMainBoxContent a[href*=matchid=]")

print([urljoin(base, a["href"]) for a in cont])
```

Which gives you:

```
['http://www.hltv.org/?pageid=188&matchid=31342', 'http://www.hltv.org/?pageid=188&matchid=31343', 'http://www.hltv.org/?pageid=188&matchid=31339', 'http://www.hltv.org/?pageid=188&matchid=31338', 'http://www.hltv.org/?pageid=188&matchid=31341', 'http://www.hltv.org/?pageid=188&matchid=31340', 'http://www.hltv.org/?pageid=188&matchid=31329', 'http://www.hltv.org/?pageid=188&matchid=31336', 'http://www.hltv.org/?pageid=188&matchid=31334', 'http://www.hltv.org/?pageid=188&matchid=31331', 'http://www.hltv.org/?pageid=188&matchid=31330', 'http://www.hltv.org/?pageid=188&matchid=31333', 'http://www.hltv.org/?pageid=188&matchid=31332', 'http://www.hltv.org/?pageid=188&matchid=31319', 'http://www.hltv.org/?pageid=188&matchid=31321', 'http://www.hltv.org/?pageid=188&matchid=31320', 'http://www.hltv.org/?pageid=188&matchid=31318', 'http://www.hltv.org/?pageid=188&matchid=31328', 'http://www.hltv.org/?pageid=188&matchid=31327', 'http://www.hltv.org/?pageid=188&matchid=31326', 'http://www.hltv.org/?pageid=188&matchid=31325', 'http://www.hltv.org/?pageid=188&matchid=31324', 'http://www.hltv.org/?pageid=188&matchid=31322', 'http://www.hltv.org/?pageid=188&matchid=31317', 'http://www.hltv.org/?pageid=188&matchid=31316', 'http://www.hltv.org/?pageid=188&matchid=31315', 'http://www.hltv.org/?pageid=188&matchid=31306', 'http://www.hltv.org/?pageid=188&matchid=31314', 'http://www.hltv.org/?pageid=188&matchid=31310', 'http://www.hltv.org/?pageid=188&matchid=31304', 'http://www.hltv.org/?pageid=188&matchid=31302', 'http://www.hltv.org/?pageid=188&matchid=31313', 'http://www.hltv.org/?pageid=188&matchid=31312', 'http://www.hltv.org/?pageid=188&matchid=31311', 'http://www.hltv.org/?pageid=188&matchid=31309', 'http://www.hltv.org/?pageid=188&matchid=31308', 'http://www.hltv.org/?pageid=188&matchid=31307', 'http://www.hltv.org/?pageid=188&matchid=31305', 'http://www.hltv.org/?pageid=188&matchid=31303', 'http://www.hltv.org/?pageid=188&matchid=31294', 'http://www.hltv.org/?pageid=188&matchid=31293', 'http://www.hltv.org/?pageid=188&matchid=31292', 'http://www.hltv.org/?pageid=188&matchid=31291', 'http://www.hltv.org/?pageid=188&matchid=31290', 'http://www.hltv.org/?pageid=188&matchid=31289', 'http://www.hltv.org/?pageid=188&matchid=31301', 'http://www.hltv.org/?pageid=188&matchid=31300', 'http://www.hltv.org/?pageid=188&matchid=31299', 'http://www.hltv.org/?pageid=188&matchid=31298', 'http://www.hltv.org/?pageid=188&matchid=31297']
```

Comment: @SHUTTEHFACE, no worries, do you not want some specific anchor tags from the page or are you actually trying to get every link with a href regardless of where it is?

Comment: I'm trying to get more specific, looking for just the href from the first column of the 'covMainBoxContent' 'class'.

Comment: @SHUTTEHFACE, the date column?

Comment: correct, just looking to get the date column links right now and eventually I will use those links to crawl further.

Comment: Thanks Padraic! Could you post the entire final code as I seem to only be getting "[u'/?pageid=188&matchid=31344', u'/?pageid=188&matchid=31342', u'/?pageid=188&matchid=31343'" where I was looking for the entire URL. Also, do you know any good places I can learn this syntax? Cheers!

Comment: @SHUTTEHFACE, you just need to join the base URL to the href, if you click on a link in your browser you will see what I mean, as far as learning about css selector  goes w3schools is a good resource, bs4 does only have limited support but enough to get a lot of what you will generally need to do. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: Thanks for the resource. Sorry but I'm new to this, how do I join the base URL to the href?

Comment: @SHUTTEHFACE, you were doing it in your own code with `"http://www.hltv.org" + link.get('href')`, using `urlparse.urljoin` is a better way  to do the same