# Trying to extract text from PDF gives me this error: "TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str"

Tags: python, pdf, pdfplumber

I am currently trying to extract the text from this whole [PDF](https://www.pidm.gov.my/PIDM/files/13/134b5c79-5319-4199-ac68-99f62aca6047.pdf). I have tried extracting the text from single pages of the PDF and it works properly but when I try to extract the whole PDF, it gives me this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/PDF_extract_1/main.py", line 35, in <module>
    extract_whole_pdf()
  File "D:/PDF_extract_1/main.py", line 26, in extract_whole_pdf
    final = final + "\n" + data
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str
```

For reference, this is the code I use when extracting from single pages:

```
def extract_first():
    pdf = pdfplumber.open("pdftest2.pdf")
    page = pdf.pages[6] #just for example, I chose page 5 of the PDF
    text = page.extract_text()

    print("First page data : {}".format(text))

    with open("pdf_pages.txt", "w", encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(text)

    pdf.close()
```

and this is the code I use to extract the whole PDF:

```
def extract_whole_pdf():
    pdf = pdfplumber.open("pdftest2.pdf")
    n = len(pdf.pages)

    final = ""
    for page in range(n):
        data = pdf.pages[page].extract_text()
        final = final + "\n" + data

    print("Whole document data : {}".format(final))

    with open("pdf_extract.txt", "w", encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(final)

    pdf.close()
```

I notice this question has been asked a lot but they don't seem to be applicable to my problem. One of the [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55449979/typeerror-can-only-concatenate-str-not-nonetype-to-str) had a similar error but it was a different situation than mine.

Comment: `extract_text()` is returning `None` at some point. Double check the documentation for that method to see what that indicates.

Comment: We expect you to perform basic diagnosis to include with your post.  At the very least, print the suspected values at the point of error and trace them back to their sources.  In many cases, doing this basic diagnosis will show you where the problem lies, and you won't need Stack Overflow at all.  IN this case, you need to track why that particular value of `page` returns no text.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the method `extract_text()` returning `None` when it finds an empty page. You can solve this by testing the data returned before concatenation:

```py
def extract_whole_pdf():
    pdf = pdfplumber.open("pdftest2.pdf")
    n = len(pdf.pages)

    final = ""
    for page in range(n):
        data = pdf.pages[page].extract_text()
        if data:
            final = final + "\n" + data

    print(f"Whole document data : {final}")

    with open("pdf_extract.txt", "w", encoding='utf-8') as f:
        f.write(final)

    pdf.close()
```

As a side note I also recommend using f-strings for string formatting as it is the latest standard.