# Spell Elements Recursive

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I have been trying to make a recursive function, which has two parameters, a word and a list, the list is the symbols of the elements as they are: H for Hydrogen, K for potassium, this is an example of what my program should return : The word Silver can be spelled as SiLvEr.

My function has some errors that I don't have clear how to correct them, I show you my function

```py
def spell_elements(palabra:str , lista:list):
    
    if palabra == "":
        return 
    
    if palabra[0] in lista:
        return palabra[0] + spell_elements(palabra.strip(palabra[0]), lista)
    
    elif palabra[:2] in lista:
        return palabra[:2] + spell_elements(palabra.strip(palabra[:2]), lista)
    
    elif palabra[:3] in lista:
        return palabra[:3] + spell_elements(palabra.strip(palabra[:3]), lista)

# Example
print(spell_elements("silver", elementos)
# output -> SiLvEr
```

The program gives me the error "TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str".
I did the debug of the function and it does it correctly but if it does not enter in any condition of the if's and elif's it gives the same problem when it enters in a good way and the word runs out of characters.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "symbols"? Also, what error are you getting with what input?

Comment: Will you expand your code example to show how you expect the function to be called and print out the returned value? Then show how you run it and the exact errors you get. You should even consider googling the error message to see if you can find a solution without waiting for us to answer you here.

Comment: Probably it's the common problem of using a function without having read its documentation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55449979/typeerror-can-only-concatenate-str-not-nonetype-to-str)

Comment: @Tacosalpastor On a side note, this code seems like it is more complex, and even inefficient, than needed to solve the problem. However, I can't be entirely sure without some more details. Specifically what is the problem you are originally trying to solve with this code? In other words, what is the purpose of the function `spell_elements ()`? What are it's expected inputs and outputs. And what are is the values of `elementos` in your example?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Yes, in fact this I sent I have to improve it a lot, the function is for those words that can be spelled only with chemical elements. . Elements is a list like this
Elements = ['H',' He', 'Li','Be','B','C',etc.]. So the function works if you give it a word like Silicon, the function should return SiLiCON, I have not yet added to ignore capitalization when searching the list Elements, the input is a word and the output is still a word but as I explained with Silicon

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in two places:

1. Just a raw `return` returns a value of `None`. So when you call `spell_elements()` recursively and try to concatenate a string, you get an error. You probably can fix this by doing `return ""`.
2. You have `if` with several `elif` but no `else`. If none of the conditions are met, the function terminates when it reaches the end and returns `None` by default. Again, you can fix this by adding `return ""` at the end of the function.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I am still a novice.

Answer (score 0):

May be you do not need a function to do it. Just use a 'dict'

```
elems={
"Silver":"SiLvEr",
"Hydrogen":"H",
"Potassium":"K"}
```

How to use it

```
print(elems["Silver"]) # output->  SiLvEr
print(elems["Hidrogen"]) # output->  H
```

You can extend the `dict`  `elems`  with other elements.
In practice  you have a `Key` and a `Value` use it as you need

```
elemS={
"SiLvEr":"Silver",
"H":"Hydrogen",
"K":"Potassium"}


print(elemS["H"]) # output->  Hidrogen
print(elemS["K"]) # output->  Potassium
```